# A query called many times with different parameters always returns the same first result

Tags: jboss, entity, resultset, entitymanager

I'm in my first Java EE project working with jboss-4.2.3, hibernate-3.2, jpa, ejb-3
I have a session bean that looks like this:

```
package ...
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import ...

@Stateless
public class myBean implements myBeanLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Item> retrieveItems (int someId) {
        String nativeQuery = "SELECT * FROM myFunc(:someId)";
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, Item.class);
        query.setParameter("someId", someId);

        List<Item> items = (List<Item>) query.getResultList();

        for (Item item : items) {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                "[%s, %s]", item.getId(), item.getQty()
            ));
        }

        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public void test () {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            retrieveItems(i);
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I call the test method, the native query executes 3 times with different parameters; the problem is after the first execution the result is the same as the first.

I checked using jdbc and the results are as expected.

```
// results using jdbc
[1, 5]
[2, 7]
[3, 6]

// results using NativeQuery (or NamedQuery)
[1, 5]
[1, 5]
[1, 5]
```

I spent the whole day trying to figure out and had no success. Any ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem clearing the entity manager. `em.clear()` I'm not sure exactly what it does or what are the consequences.